# C++ Not all control paths returning a value

Tags: c++

I have a quick question. I'm implementing a generic binary search tree.

My function is such:

```
template<class T>
T TreeSet<T>::minHelper(TreeNode<T>* rootNode) const {
    if (rootNode->left != nullptr)
        minHelper(rootNode->left);
    else
        return rootNode->data;
}
```

It is a recursive function. I can't put a return statement within the if path, however I am not sure how to return a dummy  at the end that would fix that problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you put a return statement?

Comment: Why can't you put a return in the if path?

Comment: Will that not end the function early?

Comment: Can I put "return minHelper(rootNode->left);"?

Comment: Yes, I think you should put `return minHelper(rootNode->left);` because the return statement will propogate up the recursion path.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. For whatever reason I thought that would break the recursion path before the top.

Comment: [Recursion in C and C++](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson16.html).

Comment: `return minHelper(rootNode->left)` does exactly what it says - returns the value of `minHelper(rootNode->left)`. Recursive function calls work exactly the same as other function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add `return` before the statement in the `if` path I think your function will work as your expect. Once the recursion ends (the function enters the `else` path) whatever `T` object is returned will be propagated up the recursively called functions. So in full:

```
template<class T>
T TreeSet<T>::minHelper(TreeNode<T>* rootNode) const {
    if (rootNode->left != nullptr)
        return minHelper(rootNode->left);
    else
        return rootNode->data;
}
```